# Gitlab Server on Google Kubernetes Engine mail configuration

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine

Recently I installed a new GitLab Server in a Kubernetes cluster running on `GKE`.
I followed this documentation:

- https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploying-production-ready-gitlab-on-gke

I used Helm 3 instead Helm 2.

Now I needed to configure a mail server to send emails to each operation (new user, pipelines, etc.) but I didn't find how to do that in this documentation.
I found a doc (https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html#example-configurations) but is useful only in GitLab installed in virtual machines, also I looked in the `replicaset` and `deployment`, but I can't find it.

How can I access my configurations in my GitLab Server?

- GitLab version: 13.7.0
- Helm chart: gitlab-4.7.0

Comment: Hello, have you had the chance to review this GCP documentation: [Sending email from an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail) stating that there are certain limitations when it comes to mail communication? Apart from this documentation, this options could be found in the `values.yaml` of a Helm chart pulled from the official repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As asked in the question:

> How can I access my configurations in my GitLab Server? GitLab version: 13.7.0 Helm chart: gitlab-4.7.0

You already accessed some of the configuration of your `Gitlab` by your `values.yaml` file. This is the file that stores the configuration of the resources you will be (or was) deploying.

By following one of the parts of the official documentation:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Solutions: Deploying production ready gitlab on GKE: Install the gitlab chart](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploying-production-ready-gitlab-on-gke#install_the_gitlab_chart)*

You created your own `values.yaml` and used it to override the values (only some) of the `values.yaml` file in the `Helm` Chart.

To pass additional configuration to your `Gitlab` you could either:

- Pull the whole `gitlab` chart, modify it's `values.yaml` and run it from local source:

  - `$ helm pull gitlab/gitlab --untar`
  - edit the `gitlab/values.yaml` file
  - `$ helm install gitlab gitlab/ -f gcp-values.yaml` (`gcp-values.yaml` is the values from `GCP` guide and it's in the preceding directory)
- Add to your previously created `values.yaml` configuration that is responsible for managing email communication (add to the `values.yaml` from `GCP` guide).

There are multiple parts responsible for mail communication in the `Gitlab` `values.yaml`.

For example, there is a part responsible for handling outgoing messages under `global.smtp` section:

```yaml
  ## doc/installation/deployment.md#outgoing-email
  ## Outgoing email server settings
  smtp:
    enabled: false
    address: smtp.mailgun.org
    port: 2525
    user_name: ""
    ## doc/installation/secrets.md#smtp-password
    password:
      secret: ""
      key: password
    # domain:
    authentication: "plain"
    starttls_auto: false
    openssl_verify_mode: "peer"

  ## doc/installation/deployment.md#outgoing-email
  ## Email persona used in email sent by GitLab
  email:
    from: ''
    display_name: GitLab
    reply_to: ''
    subject_suffix: ''
    smime:
      enabled: false
      secretName: ""
      keyName: "tls.key"
      certName: "tls.crt"
```

There are also parts for incoming messages, service desk etc.. You will need to check for yourself and configure it to match your needs.

The site that you mentioned:

- *[Docs.gitlab.com: Omnibus: Settings: SMTP: Example configurations](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html#example-configurations)*

Could be a good reference/guide when modifying the `values.yaml` file to support the mail configuration of your choosing.

I also encourage you to also check [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/incoming_email.html) site for incoming emails configuration.

---

As for mail communication in `GKE`.

`GKE` nodes are in fact `GCE` `VM's` and they are under certain limitations:

> ### Sending email from an instance
>
> This document describes the options for sending mail from a virtual machine (VM) instance and provides general recommendations on how to set up your instances to send email.
>
> #### Using standard email ports
>
> Due to the risk of abuse, connections to destination TCP Port 25 are [always blocked](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic) when the destination is external to your VPC network. This includes using SMTP relay with Google Workspace.
>
> Google Cloud does not place any restrictions on traffic sent to external destination IP addresses using destination TCP ports 587 or 465.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Compute: Docs: Tutorials: Sending mail](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail)*

Following on the above [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail):

I've managed to use one of the mentioned external mail service providers to configure the outgoing email communication on my `Gitlab` instance. You can choose one that suits your needs the most.

You can also check this ServerFault answer which provides some additional information:

- *[Serverfault.com: Questions: Is it possible to run an SMTP server like postfix on a Google Cloud instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/1043566/is-it-possible-to-run-an-smtp-server-like-postfix-on-a-google-cloud-instance-wit)*